# jquery value substitution

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Is this a ligitimate way of determining the selected value of an section/option box with and id of "shirt_size_1221"?

```
var user_id = '1221';
x = "#shirt_size_" + user_id ;                          
alert($(x + " option:selected"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alert` statement will always show `[object]` unless you change it to

```
alert($(x+' option:selected').val());
```

And don't worry, this is a good way of getting selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a selected option in a dropdown box by using

```
var selectList = document.getElementById("shirt_size_1221");
var val = selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].text;
```

No JQuery needed.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way is simply:

```
var user_id = '1221';
x = "#shirt_size_" + user_id ;        
alert($(x).val());
```